Is there a way to run Chrome browser on the command line so it blocks instead of being spawned?
for tessting a web app with a script I have
launch_test() {
    spawn_local_test_http_server(port)
    I want -> run_browser_with_url(where server is) 
    such that it will block until the user closes it or if one kills this process
    kill_local_test_server();
}

I am testing on MacOS

Does google-chrome fork itself to the background on MacOS? On Linux it doesn't.

Try something like this:
launch_test() {
    spawn_local_test_http_server(port)
    I want -> run_browser_with_url(where server is) 
    while pgrep "Google Chrome" > /dev/null; do
        sleep 1
    done
    kill_local_test_server();
}

